# My Login page replaced by browser authentication box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing an asp.net web application with user login. It is working fine on development environment.

When user needs to access members only page my `login.aspx` file displayed but after publishing, the when members only page request browser native login page displayed instead of my `login.aspx`. Please help me to solve this:
[image]

Comment: Can you paste the image directly inside your question? Are you using HTTP BASIC authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are using windows authentication, and it seems that your testing environment is out of the domain (machine or active directory)